# When I compare part of an array to part of another I get "Error"

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, smartface.io

This is written in javascript using he cloud IDE of smart face. But for some reason I can compare parts to lists/arrays. Please help!! Any advice or input would be greatly appreciated!

```js
var dropC = "green red blue blue blue"
var dropColors = dropC.split(" ");
var colors = ["green", "blue", "red", "yellow"];
var l = 1
var dropColor;

if (dropColors[l] == colors[0]) {
  dropColor = "green";
} else if (dropColors[l] == colors[1]) {
  dropColor = "blue";
} else if (dropColors[l] == colors[2]) {
  dropColor = "red";
} else if (dropColors[l] == colors[3]) {
  dropColor = "yellow";
} else {
  dropColor = "Error";
}
alert(dropColor);
```

Regardless the value of l the result is always "Error".

Comment: I got red - https://jsfiddle.net/4Lmg2s4b/

Comment: that is what I expect to get but I didnt

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Its for an app, look at the updated code. That more closely resembles what I am doing.

Comment: Hey, click the `Run code snippet` btn please :)

Comment: Running the snippet I get red as expected.

Comment: Wild guess... how you get your var dropC (some kind of user input)? Check length, if more than expected (24 in your example), some hidden chars are there, and then comparison could fail....

Comment: if I say alert(dropColors[l]) i get red and when I say alert(colors[2]) i get red but when i try to compare it doesn't think they are equal and returns error.

Comment: @Binary111 I tried your code on iPhone 6S and it is working, alerting expected result "red". Which device and which OS version are you trying on?